# What is a "barso"? (ref. Richard Cocks' diaries)

Tags: naval, terminology, etymology, medieval-japan

### Question

In his diaries documenting his time in Japan, Richard Cocks mentions *barsos* frequently, apparently meaning some kind of liquid containing vessel (mostly in reference to [gifts of] alcohol, but occasionally vinagre and other liquids). This word unusually is not included in the footnotes explaining almost every foreign term that he uses (mostly Japanese, with a few Portuguese and Spanish).

Does anyone know the etymology of this word?

Example usage:

> *October 28.*—Goresanos wife brought her doughter of 20 daies ould to the English howse, with a present of a *barsoe* of wyne, figges, and oringes, desiring a name to be given her, which was per consent Elizabeth.

---

<sup>**Note:** In his diaries, wine is described as also coming in *bottel, barica/barrico, barell/barrill/barille, butt* and *jarr*. Specifically *Spanish wine* is never described as coming in *barsos* (it is most commonly described as coming in *bottells*, and occasionally in *barica/barricos, barrels* or *butts*). This might suggest that *barsos* weren't European made vessels, and were a kind encountered in Japan?</sup>

---

**Data from diaries:**

[image]

Comment: The contexts  in which _barsos_ appears (which are almost always part of a visiting gift)  makes it seem more like a bottle than a barrel in size.

Comment: It often seems to be a gift of wine and food, so may just mean a standardised *gift*

Comment: Isn't there a Japanese SE? If so you might want to try your luck there.

Comment: What are the contents called "tay barso"? Identifying them might yet reveal the source of the term.

Comment: @AaronBrick I assumed tay = tea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Barso* is from  medieval Portuguese *barça* meaning "small barrel":

> #### Second word: “xxij barsos of singe”
>
> The other word I couldn’t find the root of occurs in the same letters as “singe”: where “singe” is the liquid, “barsos” are the containers. It’s quite clear from the context that a “barso” is a small barrel – from other sources it’s possible to determine that a “barso” holds c.10 litres. But the etymology evaded me: I couldn’t find “barso” in any form in Present-Day Portuguese or Spanish dictionaries, and despite the apparent connection to other words meaning ‘cask’ such as barrel, but also barrillo, barillejo, and barrico, the lack of evidence made me put my hands up.
>
> Once again, Yoshida (1993: 59) comes to the rescue. On the same page as discussed above, his list continues to section B, 酒屋, 酒造道具, 製造工程など ‘sake shop/brewery, sake production tools, manufacturing process etc’. And number 9 in this list is as follows:
>
> [image]
>
> In English:
>
> > (9) *saka-oke* (saca uoqe)   a container for sake, like an *oke* [barrel] or a *taru* [cask] (barça).
>
> ...
>
> In fine, then: it seems quite evident that barça was a common Portuguese word for a (small) barrel or a cask.

- https://samuli.kaislaniemi.fi/blog/2019/04/14/eic-drinks-in-japan/

Answer (score 9):

The meaning of "barso" is clearer than its origin. Samuli Kaislaniemi analyzed it in his PhD thesis [Reconstructing Merchant Multilingualism : Lexical Studies of Early English East India Company Correspondence](https://helda.helsinki.fi/handle/10138/228565), p. 256:

> RC uses *barso* in the sense 'little barrel' (cf. Farrington 1991:805). Etymology uncertain; does not appear in PD It., Pt., or Sp. (cf. *barrillo*, *barrilejo*); the phonology is not Japanese. Possibly a pseudo-Romance word arising from playful use of language?
>
> In his diary, RC also used *barica* [...]; Hill (1993) defines *barrico* as 'keg' (s.v.). The measures for *barsos* and "greate barelles" letters [sic] (Farrington 1991:803-805) reveal that a *barso* held *c.* 10 litres.

This rare word does not appear at all in *Merchants of Innovation: The Languages of Traders*. Perhaps Cocks invented it.

Comment: Thanks for this - I'd stumbled upon Kaislaniemi before, but when I last tried to research this topic (about a year ago) this thesis hadn't yet been published.

Comment: Kaislaniemi has found the answer (from medieval Portuguese *barça* "small barrel"): https://history.stackexchange.com/a/63643/28559

Answer (score 1):

My immediate assumption was that it was an anglicisation of Spanish *vaso* (pronounced `/'baso/`), meaning 'cup/glass/drinking vessel', since he also anglicises Spanish *recado* (message) as *reca**r**do*:

> “Copendale at Miaco not very well, and that he bringeth *recardo* from themperour to set Damian and Jno. de Lievana free.”

Further evidence that it may be Spanish in origin is that he similarly excludes the Spanish word *barica/barrico* from his section *“Some Japanese and other foreign words and terms”*, presumably because he assumed such words would be intelligible to his audience.

---

**Sources:**

<sup>• [*Diary of Richard Cocks Vol. I, Cape-Merchant in the English Factory in Japan 1615-1622, with Correspondence*](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/46803/46803-h/46803-h.htm)</sup>
 <sup>• [*Diary of Richard Cocks Vol. II, Cape-Merchant in the English Factory in Japan 1615-1622, with Correspondence*](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/48012/48012-h/48012-h.htm)</sup>